# Include jQuery in Angular 8

Tags: jquery, angular8

How can we add jQuery to angular 8?

In case of bootstrap, we install bootstrap using `npm i bootstrap` and add the link for style and script in *angular.json* file.

**Is is possible to follow such method in case of jQuery ?** If yes, please specify the steps. If not, then please give the alternate method for adding jQueryto any angular 8 application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First run npm install commands as below

```
npm install jquery --save
npm install @types/jquery --save
```

You have to add it into the angular.json file. You can look for scripts section in architect => build of angular.json file add path for jquery lib

```
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
]
```

Then in your tsconfig.app.json

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "types": ["jquery"] 
  },
  "exclude": ["test.ts", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

now you can use jquery anywhere in your project .